# Django ckeditor oembed plugin install: javascript errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-ckeditor

I have installed django-ckeditor and the admin page shows the editor
nicely. However I am having problem to add the oembed plugin to the editor.

Here's what I have:

```
# virtualenv
Django==1.6.1
South==0.8.4
django-ckeditor-updated==4.2.6
elpy==1.2.1
flake8==2.1.0
ipython==1.1.0
jedi==0.7.0
mccabe==0.2.1
pep8==1.4.6
pyflakes==0.7.3
wsgiref==0.1.2

# settings.py

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'extraPlugins': 'dialog,widget,lineutils,oembed',
        'toolbar': [
            ['About', 'oembed', ],
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice oembed requires dialog, widget, (and maybe lineutils).

Now my editor shows the oembed button, except it won't bring up a form for you to enter your video urls. Firebug shows that there are two errors:

```
TypeError: this.editor.editable(...).find is not a function
http://localhost:8000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/widget/plugin.js?t=D8AD
Line 494
TypeError: widget.wrapper.findOne is not a function
http://localhost:8000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/widget/plugin.js?t=D8AD
Line 2746
```

Django console shows that all .js, .css files are loaded.

```
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:57] "GET /admin/blog/blog/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4423
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:57] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:57] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2372
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/lang/en.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/styles.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/widget/plugin.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/lineutils/plugin.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/oembed/plugin.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/widget/lang/en.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/oembed/lang/en.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/oembed/icons/oembed.png?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/contents.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[27/Jan/2014 21:25:58] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/oembed/libs/jquery.oembed.min.js?t=D8AD HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

I have limited experience in javascript, am I missing something in the django-ckeditor plugin setting? Thanks,